# highstock Plotbands to mark certain Daytimes on X Axis

Tags: highcharts

Im trying to mark certain Day Times on my Chart - iE: 15:00 - 21:00

The Date information comes in form of a timestamp - "1365362890000" for example.

Is there any convenient way to say start from time X and go until time Y?
Else I would probs need to loop through all the times to find start/end points.

The timeframe can be anything from a day to a month.

(The plotBands themselves are working for me - just looking if there might be a better way then looping through all the data)

Edit: I meant something like you see in my picture here - its working like this and all is fine. Im just wondering if there was a simple way to say - "mark time x to time y with color z" instead of doing "by hand".

[image: chart]

Comment: The jQuery code at the bottom of the following [forum thread](https://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/plotbands-only-working-in-chrome-not-firefox-or-ie-t33347/) might provide a clue about how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, plotBands have a #from and #to property.  Just use the #from and #to of the converted datetime (i.e. the unix time * 1000)

```
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
  xAxis: {
    plotBands: [
      {
        from: 1374658200000,
        to: 1374681600000,
        color: "rgba(68, 170, 213, .2)"
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the xAxis you can set min value and tickInterval.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickInterval
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.min (should be timestamp too)

Also you can define pointStart for serie: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.pointStart and pointInterval http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.pointInterval